# Returning a String converted to Unicode in Java

Tags: java, string, ascii

I am taking a Java course and I am stumped on this question. I was to complete most of it up until the portion where I am required to convert a String to ASCII. I am able to get the first letter to output to *Edit* Unicode but it stops there. When I isolate the code on a scratch file and use a print statement it prints how it should:

```
class Scratch {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "yams";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        int numUni = (int)str.charAt(i);
        int unicode = (int)numUni;
        System.out.print(unicode + " ");
        //return unicode; //  this line will need to be changed
    }
}
```

}

Output:

```
121 97 109 115 
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is the code that I have completed so far and my issue is with Step 4:

```
public class Strings{
// STEP one - concatenateStrings()
public String concatenateStrings(String word1, String word2){
    String concantWord = word1 + " " + word2;
return concantWord;
}

// STEP two - charToASCII()
public int charToASCII(char character){
    int convertedChar = character;
return convertedChar;
}

// STEP three
public char getLastChar(String str){
    //student code here\
    int strLength = str.length();

    char lastChar = str.charAt(str.length() - 1);

    return lastChar; //  this line will need to be changed
}

 // step 4

public static String translateWord(String str){
    //student code here


        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            int numUni = (int)str.charAt(i);
            String unicode = numUni + " ";


            return unicode; //  this line will need to be changed
        }

    return "";
}

// step 5
public String madLib(String noun1, double number, String pastTenseVerb, String adjective, String noun2) {
    //student code here
    return ""; // this line will need to be changed
}
/**
 * A test block helps you test as you write. Eventually, you will learn
 * test driven development, in which every method you write will have tests you write
 * to make sure it works.
 *
 * Uncomment these lines out as you finish your various methods
 */
public void runTests() {
     System.out.println();
     //Concatenate Strings test
     System.out.println("Testing concatenateStrings method: ");
     System.out.println("Input: 'good','morning' \t Expecting: good morning\t Actual: " + concatenateStrings("good", "morning"));

     System.out.println();
     //Char to ASCII test
     System.out.println("Testing charToASCII method: ");
     System.out.println("Input: 'c' \t Expecting: 99\t Actual:" + charToASCII('c'));

     System.out.println();
     //Get Last Char test
     System.out.println("Testing getLastChar method: ");
     System.out.println("Input: 'Pterodactyl' \t Expecting: L\t Actual: " + getLastChar("Pterodactyl"));

     System.out.println();
     //Translate Word Test
     System.out.println("Testing Translate word method: ");
     System.out.println("Input: 'yams' \t Expecting: 121 97 109 115\t Actual: " + translateWord("yams"));

    // System.out.println();
    // Mad Libs Test
    // System.out.println("Testing Mad Libs method: ");
    // System.out.println("Input: 'pear, 202.356, swam, purple, bear'"
    //      + "\nExpecting: Today I went to the store and bought a pear for $202.36.\nThen I swam and saw a purple bear."
    //      + "\nActual: " + madLib("pear", 202.356, "swam", "purple", "bear"));

}


public static void main(String [] args) {
    // running test method
    Strings f = new Strings();
    f.runTests();  // this is not a static method (should it have been?) so you have to run it with the object
}
```

}

I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: It's `Unicode` (UTF-16), not `ASCII`.

Comment: @saka1029 Ugh I apologize for the mix up. I am learning about ASCII and I mixed up the terms I will fix it. Thank you for replying.

Comment: What does "convert a String to ASCII" mean? Is the output `121 97 109 115` correct for "yams", or is that what your code does but you want something else?

Comment: The instructor wants to input "yams" into the method and output yams as unicode equivalent. When I run the program I only get 121 but when I use the method by itself and output on a scratch file it outputs 121 97 109 115 which is what I am after.

Comment: You have posted a lot of code. It appears likely that most of it is not directly related to your problem - please edit your question to remove such code, leaving the absolute minimum required to show the problem.= - ie maybe a few lines only. Ideally, please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, if you return inside a loop, the loop will only ever execute once.

You want to 'build up' your string, one ascii code at a time (well, unicode codepoint, really - as others have pointed out, I don't know what dank late 80s outdated cruft you're following, mate - the days of ASCII are loooong gone), so you need a StringBuilder, you want to append 'numUni + " "' to this in the loop, and then return the stringbuilder, built up to a string:

```
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    int uni = (int) str.charAt(i);
    out.append(uni).append(" ");
}
return out.toString();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This fixed my issue. I have to read up on StringBuilder because I don't think it was taught yet. Online learning is a pain and I feel like I am missing a few things here and there.

Comment: @Drrichardhurts you don't need to use StringBuilder. Just use `String out = "";` then `out = out + uni + " ";`

Comment: Since @rzwiserloot is so concerned about proper teaching (StringBuilder instead of string concatenation) he should have pointed out to you @Drrichardhurts to avoid unnecessary type casts `int numUni = (int)str.charAt(i); int unicode = (int)numUni;` Since numUni is an integer, casting it to int is 100% unnecessary. I strongly suggest you lookup [SonarLint](https://www.sonarlint.org/) or some other [linter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)) and add it to your IDE. Linters come in handy for both experienced and newbie programmers.

Comment: It's `UTF-16`, not a `unicode codepoint`. Your code outputs surrogate pair as two numbers.

Comment: @ Uroš the actual code in the full paste did not have this extraneous cast, which seemed to indicate there was no need to explain that part. If you're going to snipe at folks in a comment, you should read the full question :)

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the ascii value immediately after the first iteration, edit your code to look something like below:

```
public static String translateWord(String str) {
    //student code here
    String ascii = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        int numascii = str.charAt(i);
        ascii += numascii + " ";
    }
    return ascii;
}
```

edit: As mentioned by commenter below, definitely read about String pool, [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and [StringBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)

Comment: This is a slamdunk case for abuse of string concatenation. It won't matter much performance wise here, but teaching bad habits to what is clearly a newbie is probably a bad idea.

Comment: well, without complicating his existing code, I was just pointing out where he went wrong, step by step learning is always good than to grab everything at once. Thanks for the feedback though